# Python For loop Iteran

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

How can I change value of a variable  which iterating over?

```
for i in range(10,30):
 print('jdvcjhc')
I want to change I value like i do in while loop

i=1`enter code here`
while i<=10
   print('dfhs')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `range` function returns a pre-calculated list of values, created from the input parameters, in this case - `(10, 30)`. Unlike `while` loop, `i` here is a 'dummy' variable used as a placeholder for the values read from the list. Within a particular iteration, one can manipulate `i` as much as they like, but it will inevitably become overwritten with the subsequent list value upon calling the next iteration.

Comment: Thanks, do check enumerate(),     for i,v in enumerate(a)

Answer (score 1):

You can't set conditional statements like (i<=10) in For loops. you just can set the range that "i" can change. Actually, if you need a condition for your loop you need to use While or For and If together.

That's my opinion.
Regards,
Shend

Edit: if you need to change the steps of adding or subtracting "i" you can use **step** in range function. ( range(start,stop,step)).